# How to optionally display ImageButton in GridView if Eval is not null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following **GridView** and **ObjectDataSource**:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In my **TemplateField** I only want to display the button if **screenshotId** evaluates to a non-null non-zero value.

If **screenshotId** is **DbNull** or 0 then I want to leave the cell blank.

I have tried this *code behind* on **RowDataBound** without success because in **GridView** I have only cell blank, also if **screenshotId** evaluates to a non-null non-zero value.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
            int screenshotId = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "screenshotId"));
            ImageButton btnShowImage = e.Row.FindControl("imgbtnEdit") as ImageButton;

            if (screenshotId > 0)
            {
                btnShowImage.Visible = true;
                Response.Write(screenshotId + "<br />"); //here the value are 1
            }
            else
            { 
                btnShowImage.Visible = false;
            }

    }

}
```

What's the best way?

Comment: Where are you checking for `DBNull.Value` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in the gridview:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Visible='<%#Eval("screenshotId") == DBNull.Value ? false : true %>' />
```

So the control Visible is set if screenshotId is null then false else true.